# Access Denied in logging into server

Tags: linux, server, virtual-machine

i was logging in as administrator in Gen4 VPS Linux server
i entered correct password few timesbut its showing `Permission denied, please try again.`

my code in command prompt is below:

```
C:\Users\Saood Ahmad>ssh root@ip adress
root@ip address's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

kindly help me out
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

On your server

```
 1. Allow ssh via firewall, port 22 (ufw or firewalld)
 2. Copy your ssh-key to your server (`ssh-copy-id`)
 3. Check on your host for firewall rules
 4. ssh-key corruption / renew your ssh-key
```